# Checking if current position (location) of device is in some particular place

Tags: objective-c, ios, gps, maps, arcgis

what i want to do is to check in which area is user.

I have gps coordinates of device and of areas (just corners). Now when i have all coordinates i should check in which area is user. I added image for illustration:

[image]

Here is 2 areas red and yellow. Device is black. In this picture i should get that user is in yellow area. I found that ArcGis sdk is for iOS so maybe i should start with it ? Or maybe there something less complicated as i need just this functionality and not really visual.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

For rectangles it is just simpler:
Just create a rectangle (`CGRect`) and use longitude as x, lat as y, and use the `CGRectContainsPoint`(rect, point).
That works for axe paralell rectangles, like the one you have drawn.